# nth-child only selecting first element

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I have the following code that I want to select a specific `class=title` using `nth-child` but it does seem to work

```
<div class="block">
   <div class="title"></div> <!-- first title here !-->
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="title"></div> <!-- second title here !-->
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="title"></div> <!-- third title here !-->
   <div class="item"></div> 
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**Test 1**

```
.title:nth-child(3){
   background-color: red;
 }
```

Expected result `Third title highlighted` but the actual output is `no highlight is done`

**Test 2**

```
.title:nth-child(1){
   background-color: red;
 }
```

Expected result `First title highlighted` The actual output is `first title is highlighted`

Am not sure why it won't work with the other child while it works with the first child only..

Comment: are you looking at a css solution or jquery

Comment: Please try the solution provided by me. I have verified the same as well.

Comment: Right now am working with jQuery but it'll be good to know if there are any CSS solution too. Am not sure if I need to open a separate thread for it.

Comment: `.title:nth-child(5){
    background-color: red;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually want to select the **third child** of the `div.block` with a class name `.title` then you must know the [child index position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child). In this case, it is **SEVEN** not *THREE*. So, you need to do something like below:

```
 .title:nth-child(7){
     background-color: red;
 }
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/iyehal/3/edit)**

---

In short, there is no child with class `title` at the position `3` in `div.block`.

**Update**:

It is not possible to select a child element without knowing whether it is present at the specified position or not using CSS. But it is possible using `jQuery`.

```
$('.title:eq(2)')  //This will search for the third child with the class .title
```

Comment: makes sense but I do not know where exactly .title will be positioned since it's dynamically generated.

Comment: @JamesWong then you must go with jQuery.

Comment: @JamesWong check my updated post. (I was busy, so I didn't updated when you had given response to me)

Answer (score 1):

With `:nth-child(n),` all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class.

With `:eq(n)` only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of any other element, and the `(n+1)`th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

So `$('.block .title:eq(2)').css('background-color','Red');` works.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `.title:nth-child(3)` does not mean “the 3rd among the elements that have the `title` attribute". Instead, it matches an element that has the `title` attribute and is the 3rd child of its parent.

There is no “nth of its class” selector in CSS. You might consider using a JavaScript workaround. But the use of a class name like `title` suggests that the elements should really be marked up as headings of some level, e.g. as `h2` instead of `div`. Doing so, you could drop the class attribute and use selectors like `h2:nth-of-type(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Test 1** would work only if you have structure like this:

```
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="title"></div>

.title:nth-child(3){
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `$('.title').siblings(':eq(3)').css('background-color', 'red');`

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/8JC7F/

or even better

```
$('.title').siblings('.title:eq(0)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Also If You want to know why your selector does not work and I quote from w3school

> The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth
>   child, regardless of type, of its parent.
>
> n can be a number, a keyword, or a formula.

so in your case

```
.title:nth-child(5){
    background-color: red;
}
```

this will work perfectly

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't always know where `.title` will show up, the list of `<div>` is dynamically generated.

Comment: hi james do u only want to select the first .title div after the first .title i.e in your example the fifth div or you want to select other .titles also?

Comment: Hi Abhijit, I would like to get the other titles as well!

Answer (score 1):

To highlight 1st div with class="title":

```
    $('div.title:eq(0)').css('background-color','red');
```

To highlight 2nd div with class="title":

```
    $('div.title:eq(1)').css('background-color','red');
```

To highlight 3rd div with class="title":

```
    $('div.title:eq(2)').css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: it works! but do you have a solution it's pure css selector? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: James See My Answer for Pure CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.eq()` jQuery method.

```
$('.block div.title:eq(0)').css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:eq(index)` selector for this

```
$('.block .title:eq(2)').css('background-color','Red');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VUgn2/)**

Answer (score 0):

`.title:nth-child(3)` means *`element with class 'title' which is the third child of it's parent`*. It's not *`which is the third element with that class`*.

Actually, you can't select *`the third element with that class`* with pure CSS.

You can use `jQuery` script, with following selector:

```
$('.title:eq(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting. Seems like there is a sequence n+1 in there. Starting from 1 it will select all subsequent classes. Here you go.

```css
.block .title:nth-child(n+1){
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <div class="title">1</div> <!-- first title here !-->
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="title">5</div> <!-- second title here !-->
   <div class="item">6</div>
   <div class="title">7</div> <!-- third title here !-->
   <div class="item">8</div> 
   <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
.title:first-of-type{
    color:#478547;

}
```

and

```
:nth-of-type()
```

to select title class